# How to write a file to the host when using Docker?

Tags: python, docker

Very new to Docker here.

I have the following very simple Dockerfile

```
FROM python
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install my_api.tar.gz
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python ./main.py
```

And my `main.py` is just

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os
import my_api

def main():
    isins_df = my_api.getInfo()
    isins_df.to_csv('data_from_docker.csv', index = False)
    print('\noutput df: \n{}'.format(isins_df))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The API comes back with the correct data. I am stuck when it comes to saving the result to the host. How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Please ask your Docker related question here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124022/docker-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `VOLUME` to your Dockerfile:

```
FROM python
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME /app
RUN pip install my_api.tar.gz
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python ./main.py
```

Then when running that image you need to pass the `--volume` flag to mount that volume to some path on the host machine:

```
docker build -t my_image .
docker run --volume=/path/on/host:/app my_image
```

If you wish to mount the volume to the directory where your building your Dockerfile, you can do it like this:

```
docker build -t my_image .
docker run --volume=$(pwd):/app my_image
```

Both of these will make it so that the contents of the container's `/app` directory and the specified directory on your host machine are "in sync", so the file your script creates in the container will appear on your host also.